# Systems Dynamics in AnyLogic - Fibonacci sequence

Tags: system, microsoft-dynamics, fibonacci, anylogic

I have a systems dynamics model in AnyLogic in which I'm trying to model the Fibonacci sequence. Yet, for some reason, my results differ from the expected ones:

Instead of

> 1,1,2,3,5,8,13...

I get

> 1, 2.137954153, 4.021788196, 7.471205823, 13.86070806...

I followed [these (spanish) instructions](http://dinamica-de-sistemas.com/revista/0905h.htm) to build my simple model.

I suppose this is not common to all software because in VenSim this example seems to work perfectly...

Can somebody explain to me why this happens in my AnyLogic program?

Comment: "Can somebody explain to me why this happens in my AnyLogic program?" Maybe, but what _is_ your program? There is no code in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because of the way differential equations are handled in each Software.

The reason you are getting the fibonacci sequence in vensim is because you are using Euler method with time step 1 (check in model settings)

If you change the integration type to RK45 in Vensim or if you reduce the time step using euler's method, you will probably get the same results as AnyLogic gets... Runge-Kutta method even though it starts with the fixed step of 1, it later changes the time step depending on the requirements of the dynamics of the model.

Now, let's understand that using a time-step of 1 in a System Dynamics model, with the model giving you wrong results with lower timesteps, means that your model is not very robust... But THAT'S WHy you get exact values in vensim... because those exact values are really extremely inaccurate for what the model really is. I would even say that the model on your link is a bad model and shouldn't be ever shown to the public.

Fortunately (or unfortunately), AnyLogic doesn't allow you to do that. You can set up a time step of 1 in the model properties, but anylogic will change the time step to something else without notice (unless you run in virtual mode, and other conditions are met)... AnyLogic only allows to use Euler+Newton in the mixed equations option, but not Euler alone.

I consider this a bug in AnyLogic that has persisted for many years and I have informed it to them, and I don't think they will ever solve it, until maybe AnyLogic 9 if we are lucky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand :)