# AnyLogic - System Dynamics : how to track stock values correctly?

Tags: java, anylogic, systemdynamics

[screenshot of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd2pf.jpg)

In the basic first order positive feedback model:

(one stock, one flow to it and a parameter gives the flow rate).

There is a `stock` with initial value of `100`, a `parameter` with the value of `0.1` and the formula of the `flow` is:

> (`flow = stock * paremeter`)

Model time units are `"years"` and we want to run the simulation for `100 years`.

The value of the `stock` over the years will be `100`, `110`, `121`, `133.1`, `146.41` ...

But the values of the `stock` over time on the simulation screen (or when I put it into a Time Plot or Data set) are `110.517`, `122.139`, `134.984`, `149.179`.

---

- Why are the values of the `stock` over time are different than the expected ones above?
- How can I track the value of the stock over years correctly?

Comment: I'm using AnyLogic 8.3.2 PLE

Comment: Why the java tag, I see nothing relating to java in your question?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Anylogic is java-based, but the question was not related. I have changed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Systems Dynamics in AnyLogic - Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098312/systems-dynamics-in-anylogic-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is the typical misconception of system dynamics. System Dynamics follow differential equations, and generally uses Euler's method to calculate the new value of Stock after each differential time step. You have the misconception that the value is updated 1 time per year, but it's not. It's updated 1 time every 0.001 time units (approximately with the default value).

I give a more extensive answer to that question here: 
[Systems Dynamics in AnyLogic - Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098312/systems-dynamics-in-anylogic-fibonacci-sequence/49111536#49111536)

Comment: Felipe - Thank you for your answer. I understand now.